# Test de Wald manual

Tags: regresión-lineal

Intento entender el test de Wald en regresión logística, pero al usar la fórmula me salen una cosa distinta.
La fórmula que uso es la siguiente:

S = (X<sup>t</sup>VX)<sup>-1</sup>

Donde X es la matriz *r x k+1* de las variables independientes (con la constante en primer lugar) y V es la matriz diagonal cuyos elementos son v<sub>ii</sub> = p<sub>i</sub>(1-p<sub>i</sub>), siendo *p* la probabilidad calculada para cada elemento. Las raíces cuadradas de los elementos diagonales serían los desvíos estándar de los parámetros.

Lo saqué de http://www.real-statistics.com/logistic-regression/significance-testing-logistic-regression-coefficients/ pero es básicamente la misma en todos los lugares que busqué.
Ahora, la intento sacar mediante esta fórmula y me da una cosa distinta a la que me sacaría un modelo.
Use R para crear un dataset con datos aleatorios:

```r
set.seed(5674)

prueba <- cbind.data.frame(a = sample(seq(0,3,length.out = 5000), size = 1000,
                                      replace = TRUE),
                           b = sample(seq(0,3,length.out = 5000), size = 1000,
                                      replace = TRUE),
                           c = sample(seq(0,3,length.out = 5000), size = 1000,
                                      replace = TRUE),
                           d = sample(seq(0,3,length.out = 5000), size = 1000,
                                      replace = TRUE),
                           e = sample(seq(0,3,length.out = 5000), size = 1000,
                                      replace = TRUE))


prueba$y <- sapply(1:1000, function(x){
  ex <- exp(0.3*prueba$a[x] + 0.25*prueba$b[x] - 0.4 * prueba$c[x] - 
              0.15 * prueba$d[x] - 0.05*prueba$e[x])
  x1 <- ex/(ex+1)
  x2 <- 1/(ex+1)
  t <- sample(0:1, size = 1, prob = c(x2,x1))
  return(t[1])
})
```

Ahora creo el modelo, y saco la probabilidad predicha:

```r
modelo <- glm(y ~ a+b+c+d+e, data = prueba)
w <- modelo$fitted.values
w1 <- w*(1-w)
```

Luego utilizo la formula que puse antes para sacar la matriz de varianzas - covarianzas:

```r
matriz <- cbind(cons = rep(1,1000), as.matrix(prueba[,1:5]))

matriz1 <- apply(matriz, 2, function(x){x * w1})

varianza <- t(matriz1) %*% matriz
varianza1 <- solve(varianza)
sqrt(varianza1[1,1])
```

La última línea es para ver el desvío estándar de la variable a. Me da esto:

```
[1] 0.07855672
```

Lo cual es distinto de lo que me informa el modelo:

```r
summary(modelo)[[12]]
```

```
               Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.46925485 0.06153214  7.6261742 5.641569e-14
a            0.08539726 0.01776354  4.8074451 1.764783e-06
b            0.06246717 0.01793220  3.4835200 5.164320e-04
c           -0.09870667 0.01752367 -5.6327620 2.307966e-08
d           -0.04879819 0.01752240 -2.7849038 5.456082e-03
e           -0.01540819 0.01715283 -0.8982882 3.692495e-01
```

¿Hay algún error en la fórmula?